# Sequelize transactioons with stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Im facing a weird problem which I would need some assistance with.

I am using transactions in a scenario where Im inserting data to multiple tables.

I have a stored proc in a mysl db where the following is happening:

> step 1: INSERT INTO TABLE1 --- SUCCESS
>
> step2: INSERT INTO TABLE2 ---SUCCESS
>
> step 3 INSERT INTO TABLE3 --- FAILURE

The weird part is that when the rollback occurs via sequlize it only occurs on TABLE3 and not on the first two inserts.

The code:

```
export const executor = async (query: Function, db: any) => {
  try {
    const result = await db.sequelize.transaction(async t => {
      const resp = await query(t);

      return resp;
    });

    // If the execution reaches this line, the transaction has been committed successfully
    // `result` is whatever was returned from the transaction callback (the `user`, in this case)
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    // If the execution reaches this line, an error occurred.
    // The transaction has already been rolled back automatically by Sequelize!

    // log here

    console.log('ERROR', error);

    throw new Error('Internal server error');
  }
};
```

I call my stored proc like this:

```
const r = await executor(
  param =>
    db.sequelize.query(
      'CALL registerUser(:email, :password, :roleId, :firstName, :lastName, :age, :jobTitle, :prefLanguageId, :assigned, :expId, :imageId, :tableId, :position)',
      {
        replacements: {
          email: args.input.Email,
          password: PasswordHash,
          roleId: 1,
          firstName: args.input.FirstName,
          lastName: args.input.LastName,
          age: new Date(new Date(args.input.Age).toUTCString()),
          jobTitle: args.input.JobTitle,
          prefLanguageId: 1,
          assigned: false,
          expId: '9b42b3d0-b227-11ea-b63f-9746e0754cfe',
          imageId,
          tableId: null,
          position: null,
        },
      },
      { transaction: param }
    ),
  db
    );
```

As I mentioned above a `INSERT` in one of the tables in the stored proc is failing and this is by design since im testing but I would expect that all data that has been inserted to all tables would get removed when rollback is called.

Am I thinking about this wrong? I could setup a transaction in the proc itself but kind of defeats the purpose of using sequelize for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed an object with the `transaction` prop as the third parameter but you should pass it next to `replacements` prop in the second parameter:

````
db.sequelize.query(
      'CALL registerUser(:email, :password, :roleId, :firstName, :lastName, :age, :jobTitle, :prefLanguageId, :assigned, :expId, :imageId, :tableId, :position)',
      {
        replacements: {
          email: args.input.Email,
          password: PasswordHash,
          roleId: 1,
          firstName: args.input.FirstName,
          lastName: args.input.LastName,
          age: new Date(new Date(args.input.Age).toUTCString()),
          jobTitle: args.input.JobTitle,
          prefLanguageId: 1,
          assigned: false,
          expId: '9b42b3d0-b227-11ea-b63f-9746e0754cfe',
          imageId,
          tableId: null,
          position: null,
        },
        transaction: param
      })```
````